# Cypress login with Identity Server failing with "Invalid redirect_uri"

Tags: angular, cypress, identityserver4

I have an angular SPA that is locked behind an implementation of Identity Server. This works perfectly well while running locally.

However, when I try to run my Cypress tests with he following login command:

```js
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    login(email: string, password: string): void;
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
  cy.get('#Email').type(email);
  cy.get('#Password').type(password);
  cy.get('#LoginButton').click();
  cy.wait(2000);
});
```

After attempting to authenticate, it throws me to a "400 - Something went" wrong page. This isn't particularly helpful so I looked in our logs and found the following couple of errors:

```
Time    12:14:58
Exception type  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException
Exception message   The required antiforgery cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxxxxx" is not present.
RequestPath /Account/Login
ThreadId    30
ParentId    0000000000000000
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxxxxx" is not present.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
```

and the other error that seems like it might be related is:

```
Time    12:24:45
Message Invalid redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4200/silent-renew.html" AuthorizeRequestValidationLog { ClientId: "clientId", ClientName: "ClientName", RedirectUri: null, AllowedRedirectUris: ["http://localhost:4200", ..., "http://localhost:4200/callback"], SubjectId: "REMOVED", ResponseType: null, ResponseMode: null, GrantType: null, RequestedScopes: "", State: null, UiLocales: null, Nonce: null, AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses: null, DisplayMode: null, PromptMode: null, MaxAge: null, LoginHint: null, SessionId: null, Raw: [("client_id": "clientId"), ("redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/silent-renew.html"), ("response_type": "code"), ("scope": "openid profile OTHER_SCOPE"), ("nonce": "REMOVED"), ("state": "REMOVED"), ("code_challenge": "REMVOED"), ("code_challenge_method": "S256"), ("prompt": "none")] }
RequestPath /connect/authorize
ThreadId    166
ParentId    0000000000000000
```

In an earlier version log in identity server it says the request starting is:

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://IDENTITY_SERVER_URL/connect/authorize?client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fsilent-renew.html&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20OTHER_SCOPE&nonce=REMOVED&state=REMOVED&code_challenge=REMOVED&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none
```

It looks like this url contains everything that is marked as null in the previous log, so don't know if that log is just not showing everything.

Has anyone else had this before that can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a tip that might be useful for you, I'm doing something similar but using Keycloak (another OIDC provider, just like Identity Server). Instead of doing a manual login via the UI, I'm using the REST API to get an access token and then store it in `window.sessionStorage`. In this way I'm avoiding the re-direct hell that you're experiencing.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back - thank you!

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Can you give an example code how to do this with Keycloak. I have the same scenario and would appreciate a solution for that.